# Why does v[1+(0×(⍴v))] produce a rank error and not the first item in a 2d array?

Tags: rank, apl

First, I assign v as:

```
v ← ⍳(4 9)

v
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│0 0│0 1│0 2│0 3│0 4│0 5│0 6│0 7│0 8│
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│1 0│1 1│1 2│1 3│1 4│1 5│1 6│1 7│1 8│
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│2 0│2 1│2 2│2 3│2 4│2 5│2 6│2 7│2 8│
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│3 0│3 1│3 2│3 3│3 4│3 5│3 6│3 7│3 8│
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

Next I try to access the upper left element like so:

```
v[1+(0×(⍴v))]
```

Instead, I get a rank error

What's happening here?

Comment: APL has many ways to [index](https://help.dyalog.com/18.2/#Language/Primitive%20Functions/Indexing.htm) `v[⊂1+0×⍴v]` is what you want

Answer (score 2):

You are essentially computing v[1 1] while you probably meant to compute v[1;1]. Also try: (1+0×⍴v) ⌷ v